# Could we get an image resizer built into image upload, please? Please!

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

Many users will want to load photos directly from their phones. With modern phone camera resolution, SE will usually block these and tell the user the image must be resized first.

Many cell-phone users honestly do not know how to change resolution, and even for those who do this may mean having to send the image to another machine for processing, which is a non-trivial inconvenience.

It really should be easy for SE to instead automatically convert images to a standard size, and not much harder to only convert those which are oversized. Tools and libraries to do this are near-universally available.

I honestly don't see a significant reason *not* to automatically resize. If you are worried about DOS attacks you can still reject images which are *completely* unreasonable.

Comment: Might be possible to do this client-side, such as with a userscript and an external JavaScript library

Comment: I grant it's a duplicate. However, I see nothing resembling an actual answer there. So, no, it doesn't. If there is a Good Reason for ignoring the repeated request, please explain so we can try to refine the suggestion to address that. If the team simply has no interest, say that explicitly. ... Is there a public Jira or equivalent for SE, so we can see actual design decision status and priorities?

Comment: While the automated comment asks if the linked question answers your question, duplicate closure is a bit different on Meta in that we try to keep track of feature requests and bug reports and only stick to having one open question for organizational purposes.

Comment: As for the status of that feature request, it is tagged with [tag:status-review] which essentially just means that it's on staff radar. Without further updates to it, we do not know when, or if, it will be addressed.

Comment: OK. Still sounds like a real ticketing system would serve you far better, but...

Comment: @keshlam There's a real ticketing system but it's only visible internally (to SE staff). The ticketing system that's public is basically this site. It serves both as a ticketing system and discussion space for potential changes. Community buy-in is established here at which point staff can observe that there's backing behind a feature request before passing it to a developer.

Comment: Well, took them 12 years to develop a decent responsive design, so going to take at least that much until they have decent image upload fitting for mobile devices. 20 years isn't lots of time, it will just fly by. Let's visit here in 20 years and see if I was correct. :-)

Comment: +1, too much human time wasted on some easily automatable image resizing.